# R extract Date and Time Info

Tags: r, date, as.date

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
> df1
   Date         Name    Surname   Amount
2015-07-24      John     Smith     200
```

I want to extrapolate all the infos out of the Date into new columns, so I can get to this:

```
> df2
   Date     Year  Month   Day    Day_w      Name    Surname   Amount
2015-07-24  2015    7     24    Friday      John     Smith     200
```

So now I'd like to have Year, Month, Day and Day of the Week. How can I do that? When I try to first make the variable a date using as.Date the data.frame gets messed up and the Date all become NA (and no new columns). Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does `class(df1$Date)` give you?

Comment: class(df1$Date)
factor

Comment: See the functionality of `lubridate`. You can extract any time period you want, and probably more.

Comment: Why is the year is `2013`, the month is `3` while Your date is `2015-07-24`

Comment: @RomanLuštrik- Brutus, you too?

Comment: Edited, David. Apologies.

Comment: I also checked lubridate, but I can't get it to work somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
df2 <- df1
dates <- strptime(as.character(df1$Date),format="%Y-%m-%d")
df2$Year <- format(dates, "%Y")
df2$Month <- format(dates, "%m")
df2$Day <- format(dates, "%d")
df2$Day_w <- format(dates, "%a")
```

Afterwards you can rearrange the order of columns in `df2`as you desire.

Comment: Ok this is weird. I tried doing again the same command with a similar dataset and now all the new columns have NA values in it. What's going wrong this time?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Difficult to say where the problem is. Does the name of the original column ("Date") correspond to that of your new dataset? Note that the code is case-sensitive. Is the format of the date exactly the same as in you example? Maybe you can post a small portion of the new dataset with `head(similar_df)` as an edit of your OP. This could help understanding what went wrong.

Comment: If all the new columns are NAs, the error is almost certainly due to the reading of the dates, in line 2 of the above code. I therefore assume that either the date format, the column name, or the variable type poses some problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple and efficient solution using the `devel` version of `data.table` and its new `tstrsplit` function which will perform the splitting operation only once and also update your data set *in place*.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Day_w") := 
             c(tstrsplit(Date, "-", type.convert = TRUE), wday(Date))]
df1
#          Date Name Surname Amount Year Month Day Day_w
# 1: 2015-07-24 John   Smith    200 2015     7  24     6
```

Note that I've used a numeric representation of the week days because there is an efficient built in `wday` function for that in the `data.table` package, but you can easily tweak it if you really need to using `format(as.Date(Date), format = "%A")` instead.

---

In order to install the devel version use the following

```
library(devtools)
install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)
```