# R extract Date and Time with Timezone

Tags: r, timestamp

I originally asked a simpler question on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648858/r-extract-date-and-time-info) and the answer worked fine. However, I now need to do the same thing with a dataset from another country for which I need change the timezone for consistency with my analysis.

So here's a row from my df:

```
df
      Date            Name    Surname   Amount
2015-07-24 23:15:07   John     Smith     200
```

Let's say I want to convert to timezone +8 hours and extract time and date in different columns. Here's what I'd like it to be:

```
df1
       Date           Year  Month   Day    Day_w   Hour Minute Seconds  Name    Surname   Amount
2015-07-24 23:15:07   2015    7     25    Saturday  07    15     07     John     Smith     200
```

As you can see the original Date column remains the same, but the new column automatically converts the time (7am from 11pm) and also changes the day if necessary (in this case from 24 to 25; and from what was supposed to be Friday to Saturday).

I suppose I can first convert the whole Date column to the new timezone and then split dates and times, but how do I make it change the day automatically if the time requires it to be so (like in my example)?

Thanks!

Comment: `strptime` has a `tz` argument to specify the timezone of your data.  What value are you using for that?

Comment: I know the timezone of my data, but I also know it's wrong. So I need to add +8 hours to it, but I want it to change automatically the day as well if needed (e.g. if it's 11pm and I add 8h then it shifts to 7am of the following day). Afterwards I want to split it in multiple columns (if these two things can't be done simultaneously)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your date is in a string format, i.e `d <- "2015-07-24 23:15:07"`.

You can convert it to date based on your local timezone with `as.POSIXct`.

```
> a <- as.POSIXct(d)
> a
[1] "2015-07-24 23:15:07 MYT"
```

(MYT is my local timezone)

And you can convert the same date-time in another timezone specifying `tz`, e.g.

```
> b <- as.POSIXct(b, tz="Japan")
> b
[1] "2015-07-24 23:15:07 JST"
```

For you can convert them to other time zones by changing the `tzone` attribute. E.g. I want to convert my first variable with local time to the same timezone as the second one

```
> attr(a, "tzone") <- "Japan"
> a
[1] "2015-07-25 00:15:07 JST"
```

(If you want to change to your local time zone, set the `tzone` to `""`)

If you want to extract just the time, use `format`

```
> format(a, "%H")
[1] "00"
```

or the full date time

```
> format(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2015-07-25 00:15:07"
> format(b, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2015-07-24 23:15:07"
```

Comment: I tried this: 
     > b <- as.POSIXct(b, tz="Japan")
     > b
     [1] "2015-07-24 23:15:07 JST"

But it's not working. Nothing happens and the date/time stay the same...

Comment: Not sure what you meant not the same? it seems to be what's expected, that tit shows that `b` is set with a "JST" time zone.

Basically use `as.POSIXct` to set the time based on the actual timezone, as `POSIXct` will convert it to a universal time (regardless of timezone) which it stores. Then use the `attr` portion to set what timezone you want it to be displayed, and then the conversion will be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package lubridate. And there is anarticle on [revolution analytics](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/06/converting-time-zones.html) about this.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Date = ymd_hms("2015-07-24 23:15:07"), Name = "John", Surname = "Smith", Amount = 200, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# date in UTC
df$Date
"2015-07-24 23:15:07 UTC"

# show timezone if you go to +8 hrs, from UTC / GMT to Shanghai.
# df$Date is not changed into new timezone
with_tz(df$Date, tzone = "Asia/Shanghai")
"2015-07-25 07:15:07 CST"    

# create output df and for each extraction change timezone
df <- df %>% mutate(year = year(with_tz(df$Date, tzone = "Asia/Shanghai")),
                    month = month(with_tz(df$Date, tzone = "Asia/Shanghai")),
                    day = day(with_tz(df$Date, tzone = "Asia/Shanghai")),
                    hour = hour(with_tz(df$Date, tzone = "Asia/Shanghai")),
                    minute = minute(with_tz(df$Date, tzone = "Asia/Shanghai")),
                    second = second(with_tz(df$Date, tzone = "Asia/Shanghai")))
# print df
df

                 Date Name Surname Amount year month day hour minute second
1 2015-07-24 23:15:07 John   Smith    200 2015     7  25    7     15      7
```

Comment: The mutate function works in splitting the time into different columns, but it does not return the new changed time....

Comment: @Billaus, Actually it does. See the change in hour from 23 to 7 in the mutate. 23 in GMT timezone and 7 in Shanghai timezone. Also the dates switch as they should.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
# For Current date and time
d = now()
d = force_tz(d, "America/Chicago")
hour(d) = hour(d)+8;
df1 = data.frame(Date = d, Year = year(d),     Month = month(d), Day = day(d), Day_w = wday(d,label=T), Hour = hour(d), Minute = minute(d),     Seconds = second(d), Name ="John", Surname = "Smith", Amount=200)
print(df1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't serve my purpose because it'd change only the hour by +8, when I want it to change the day automatically as well in the case that adding +8 hours bring the time to the next day...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found an answer. Assuming my times are recorded in Sydney time and I want to convert it to UK time:

```
#Assigns new column as date

df$Date1 <- as.POSIXct(df$Date, tz="Australia/Sydney")

#Convert it to desired time

attributes(df$Date1)$tzone <- "Europe/London"
```

It worked fine for me, so I thought I'd post it in case others needed it too.

Comment: This actually is the same as my answer above.